# Android 2D-game, best choice for graphics?

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es, 2d, android-canvas

We are 2 guys without experience in Android development and 2D-games.

We want to make a 2D game with fairly simple graphics for Android phones. It is basically a city seen from above. Buildings would just be rectangles. Then we will have simple characters as small circles.
We need to continously update the screen. There will be some AI(pathfinding and collisiondetection).

What would be the best way to do the graphics? 
What are the pros and cons of OpenGL, Canvas and Graphics?
Maybe canvas is slower but easier to use than OpenGL. Maybe 2 people without experience can make a better game with Canvas or Graphics than with OpenGL even though OpenGL has more potential? 
We have roughly one month of full working days to put in.

We have an idea to use google maps as well, then I guess that would be a bitmap. Does that change things?

We will program in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are going to want to use `SurfaceView` and implement your own game loop. It is pretty easy to get up and running. You may also want to check out a game engine such as AndEngine or LibGDX.

AndEngine and LibGDX handle all of the set-up work for you and they are pretty nice to use. LibGDX is my favorite as it allows for more lower level access and I have found has better performance. And allows you to do all of your testing right on your computer and deploy to the device only when you need to.

If you aren't that familiar with OpenGL then it will definitely have a learning curve and I think you will spend the majority of your time learning it rather than jumping right and making something. If all you need is 2D then `SurfaceView` will be more than enough based on your description. You can do all of your collision detection with bounding rectangles which is super easy in Android.

Comment: I found the SufaceView nice and easy.. but when I had to rotate bitmaps it got quite slow. I am trying OpenGL now.

Answer (score 3):

Don't bother with OpenGL if all you are doing is a simple 2D game.

Comment: This information is false since it's all relative. If I would create a 2D-MarioClone I would use openGL since it's performance is faster.

Answer (score 3):

You could try AndEngine. There are some samples with collision detection and 2D Games and so on:
http://www.andengine.org/
It's a free Android 2D OpenGL Game Engine. Look at Youtube for some tutorials how to set it up (its a bit tricky).

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend NME. It gets great performance on Android (7 times faster than AIR, and 5 times faster than Corona, roughly), is free and mirrors the Flash API, so its easy to use.

Plus, after you're done, the game will also build for Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, webOS, Flash and even HTML5 if you want it to.

http://www.haxenme.org

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer openGL for this, but using Game Engine will be more convenient. For Graphics in continuous loop should have best algorithm otherwise your FPS may jitter. Choice among two options given above, surely OpenGL. But be specific about your content and graphics while designing it. Check my blog on what to choose for game development

[Android Game Development - WHAT TO CHOOSE
Canvas or OpenGL or LibGDX or Game Engines!!](http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2017/06/what-to-choose-for-android-game.html)

HOPE this may be helpful for you..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you Libgdx. I have been using it for a month and i already got used to it.
It is fairly simple and everything you will need to create a game for android , pc/mac/linux
,html is packed in as "gdx.*". It has classes like rectangle, sprite, batch renderer and anything you will need for a 2d game.

I also heard andengine people liked though but i never used it soo your choice.